# Запуск и остановка java файлов через task scheduler

Tags: java, windows, cmd, task

Подскажите как правильно запустить java файлы на удаленном компе через task sheduler. Пробовала сделать двумя способами:

1. Запустить сам java файл. Запуск осуществляется, но мне необходимо,
   чтобы процесс оставался висеть в командной строке, а не сразу же
   закрывался. Изменить java файл возможности нет.
2. Записать запуск java файла в bat. В таком случае запуск происходит нормально, и процесс остается висеть в командной строке,
   но так как у командной строки свое название, то остановить задачу я
   потом не могу.

Comment: Можно написать свою программу, которая будет контролировать вызов и мониторинг программы, либо (в случае windows) через .bat скрипт, java -jar и на следующей строке pause, что бы консоль не закрывалась

Comment: Мне нужно именно через task sheduler. Через bat скрипт запускается консоль, но потом у меня не получается ее закрыть тем же таском в task sheduler, так как этот файл имеет другое имя, а в task shedulere написано именно запуск/остановка test.bat

Comment: Не понятно в чем проблема с вариантом №2? Консольное окно можно найти по команде запуска. К примеру найти и "убить" окно java запущенное (с такими то параметрами) можно следующей командой: wmic process where (name="java.exe" and commandline like "java.exe -Xmn2G%" ) call terminate